# How do I complete little girl quest after smashing red jewel brooch?

Tags: bloodborne

So I smashed the red jewel brooch to get the blood gem but now when I talk to the little girl she asks if I found her mum yet. And the only thing I can answer is no. Following that she asks if she should go and find her parents.[image] Again the only answer is no. Then that’s basically the end of the conversation. So can can someone please tell what I’m supposed to do at this point.

Answer (score 5):

It's OK not to give her Red Jeweled Brooch.

At this point you have three possible ways to continue her quest:

1. Visit Iosefka again and you will be able to send little girl to her clinic.
2. Visit Oedon Chapel and send the girl there.
3. Don't do anything - and the girl will leave to search her parents, and eventually something will happen to her in other location.

I've tried to minimize spoilers, but if you want to know details anyway - here is her quest progression - [Viola](https://bloodborne.wiki.fextralife.com/Viola).

Comment: I don't believe the quest will auto-advance. You need to send her off to a different location for anything new to happen.